# How to implement an "any" option for product attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, catalogsearch

I have a clothing store where all products have a size and color, and I want to add a new "make-your-own-shirt" product on the site. If someone wants to see all purple shirts on my site, they should see the tailor-made shirt in the search results because tailor-made shirts can come in any color.

This is a dumbed-down example. Note that right now, multiple colors and sizes of the same shirt are all standalone products.

I'm using ManaDev for filtering - but I'm not the one who set it up and know little about it.

I have a very ugly solution right now: my custom-made search page automatically adds the "any" value to filters, so that whenever you search for a shirt that is small and purple, you actually search for a product with `size = small OR any` and `color = purple OR any`. But this is quite hard to maintain and an ugly fix that is visible to the user. I'd rather fix this server-side. Is there any way to make such a value that matches any search filter?